# Hive create external table

Tags: hive, parseexception

I'm trying to create the table in the hive but am getting the below-mentioned error. Can anyone help me what is the issue?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flightInfo2008
(Year INT,
Month INT,
DayofMonth INT,
DayOfWeek INT,
DepTime INT,
CRSDepTime INT,
ArrTime INT,
CRSArrTime INT,
UniqueCarrier STRING,
FlightNum INT,
TailNum STRING,
ActualElapsedTime INT,
CRSElapsedTime INT,
AirTime INT,
ArrDelay INT,
DepDelay INT,
Origin  STRING,
Dest STRING,
Distance INT,
TaxiIn INT,
TaxiOut INT,
Cancelled INT,
CancellationCode INT,
Diverted INT,
CarrierDelay INT,
WeatherDelay INT,
NASDelay INT,
SecurityDelay INT,
LateAircraftDelay INT)
COMMENT 'mydb flightInfo2008'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/user/hadoop/mydata';
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 15:10 cannot recognize input near ',' 'ArrDelay' 'INT' in column type
>   hive>

Comment: it seems to be ok, you could take a  look to your script to check if you see some special characters. Also, try changing the names for year and month, there are udfs with those names and maybe hive is not being very clear about the exception. what Hive version are you using?

Comment: Check for TAB symbols and replace them with spaces

Comment: @lake I have changed year and month but it's still not working and I'm using Hive 1.2.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

Look for some special character that might be added while copying the text from a notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Running your CREATE statement from hive:

> FAILED: ParseException line 33:22 mismatched input '' expecting StringLiteral near 'BY' in table row format's field separator

From beeline:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 33:22 mismatched input '' expecting StringLiteral near 'BY' in table row format's field separator (state=42000,code=40000)

In both cases the problem is with

> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'

which should be written as

> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'

After this modification I created the table both from hive and beeline.

Impala-shell accepts both ';' and '\;' and creates the table successfully.

But your error message is not the same as my ones. So I agree with already given answers that apparently the problem is with invisible special character(s) near ArrDelay.